# Typescript wrapping function with generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How can I wrap a function without changing its generic type in Typescript?

```
function x() {
  console.log('Original Function');
}

function wrapper<T extends Function>(func: T): T {
  // Typescript compiler error:
  // Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  return () => {
    console.log('Wrapped Function');
    func.call(null);
  }
}

const xWrapped = wrapper(x);
xWrapped(); // logged 'Wrapped Function' & 'Original Function'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The wrapper function is expected to take in a function and return a function of the exact same type signature.

Typescript has no way of knowing how many arguments the passed function takes or what it returns and your function implicitly assumes that it takes 0 arguments (except this) and returns void.

There isn't a nice way to save function signatures in typescript at the moment. However there is a new proposal for later versions that may fix this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453

For now you can make a generic wrapper that looks something like this.

```
function wrapper<T extends (...args:any[])=>any>(func: T): T {
  return <T>((...args:any[]) => {
        console.log('Wrapped Function');
        return func(...args);
    });
}
```

With the proposal for Variadic types this function could be written like this

```
function wrapper<...TArgs,TRet>(func:(...args:...TARGS)=>TRet) {
    return (...args:...TARGS) => {
        console.log("Wrapped function");
        return func(...args);
    }
}
```

Note the main difference here is that there is no cast the above solution had to tell the compiler that the return variable was the same type as the input variable. However with variadic types the arguments themselves can be typed generically.
(Note variadic types are not currently in typescript and when the do get included it is fully possible that the above code has syntax errors)

**Update for TypeScript 4.3 release:**
with implemented proposal working code for wrapper will look like

```
type InferArgs<T> = T extends (...t: [...infer Arg]) => any ? Arg : never;
type InferReturn<T> = T extends (...t: [...infer Arg]) => infer Res ? Res : never;

function getWrapper<TFunc extends (...args: any[]) => any>(func: TFunc)
    : (...args: InferArgs<TFunc>) => InferReturn<TFunc> {

    return (...args: InferArgs<TFunc>) => {
        // something before

        try {
            return func(...args);
        } finally {

            // something after;
        }
    };
}
```

Some short but helpful info regarding usage of Variadic Tuples with examples can be found here: https://fettblog.eu/variadic-tuple-types-preview/.

Comment: How would this proposal fix this issue?

Comment: @PRAISER
You could specify  a list of generic types for your function arguments. The example shows the use of a fully generic curry/partial application function. This means that things like fn.bind and fn.apply can hopefully be type safe in the future to.

Comment: What if the function we want to use `InferArgs` on a function that has generic parameters? How would you copy the genericness to the wrapping function?

Comment: As of TypeScript 3.1 there are `Parameters<T>` and `ReturnType<T>` utility types that are very similar to the `InferArgs` and `InferReturn` types defined in this answer.

Answer (score 12):

Here's an alternative that preserves the argument and returns types of the inner function without depending on variadic types.

```
function x(message: string): void {
    console.log(`inner ${message}`);
}

export function wrapper<Args extends any[], Return>(
    operation: (...operationParameters: Args) => Return, 
    ...parameters: Args
): Return {
    console.log(`outer `);

    return operation(...parameters);
}

x("abc");
wrapper(x, "xyz");

// output:
//
// inner abc
// outer
// inner xyz
```

When `wrapper` is called with `x`, the TS compiler infers its type as `function wrapper<[string], void>(operation: (operationParameters_0: string) => void, parameters_0: string): void`.

If you try to call `wrapper(x, 123)`, it fails with beautiful type safety: `Argument of type '123' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.`

Answer (score 4):

I prefer a simpler solution, like bellow:

```js
function wrapFunction<TArgs extends any[], TReturn>(
  targetFunction: (...parameters: TArgs) => TReturn,
): (...parameters: TArgs) => TReturn {
  return (...parameters: TArgs) => {
    console.log(`Hello, what is your name?`);
    return targetFunction(...parameters);
  };
}


// --------------- Example
const someFunction = (name: string) => {
    console.log(`Hey! My name is ${name}.`);
}

const wrappedFunction = wrapFunction(someFunction);
wrappedFunction("Fábio");
```

Output

```
[LOG]: "Hello, what is your name?" 
[LOG]: "Hey! My name is Fábio."
```

Or, if you want something more generic:

```js
export function wrapFunction<TArgs extends any[], TReturn>(
  targetFunction: (...parameters: TArgs) => TReturn,
  wrapperFunction: (...parameters: TArgs) => void,
): (...parameters: TArgs) => TReturn {
  return (...parameters: TArgs) => {
    wrapperFunction(...parameters);
    return targetFunction(...parameters);
  };
}



// --------------- Example
const someFunction = (name: string) => {
    console.log(`Hey! My name is ${name}.`);
}

const wrapperFunction = (name: string) => {
    console.log(`The wrapper - Hey! My name is ${name}.`);
}

const wrappedFunction = wrapFunction(someFunction, wrapperFunction);
wrappedFunction("Fábio");
```

Output

```
[LOG]: "The wrapper - Hey! My name is Fábio." 
[LOG]: "Hey! My name is Fábio."
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way I found. It keeps even the generics of the wrapped function:

```
const newFunction = ((one, two) => {
    // something before
    const result = oldFunction(one, two)
    // something after
    return result
}) as typeof oldFunction
```